# Django не перезагружается сервер

Tags: django

Такой вопрос: пользуюсь джанго и после внесения правок иногда надо ребутнуть сервер, но по какой-то причине он не ребутается, т.е. я его выключаю и включаю командой python manage.py runserver, но страница грузится не будет. Нужно его запускать на новом порте и так каждый раз, помогает только перезагрузка компьютера
Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: Где и как включаете, где и как выключаете?

Comment: В Pycharm в консоли Debian

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нашёл ответ на данный вопрос, по какой-то причине этого в консоли не писало, но нужно было просто освободить порт для повторного его использования командой

`sudo fuser -k 8000/tcp`

Comment: Однако остаётся открытым вопрос, почему у вас порт вообще остаётся занят, такого быть в норме не должно

Comment: К сожалению, на данный вопрос ответить вам не смогу, возможно проблемы самого пайчарма и у него остаются какие-то остатки сервера на данном порте

Comment: совет в стиле: «болит голова? так давай её отрубим! результат гарантирован!»

Comment: Я задавал ответ на нескольких форумах и на анлийском стаке тоже, как видите никто в принципе другого решения не дал, так что не понимаю ваше негодование